Suppress stdout message from C/C++ library
I am attempting to suppress a message that is printed to stdout by a library implemented in C.
My specific usecase is OpenCV, so I will use it for the MCVE below. The estimateChessboardSharpness function has a printout when the grid size is too small (which happens here). I made a PR to fix it, but in the meantime, I'd like to suppress the message. For example:
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((512, 640), dtype='uint8')
corners = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(8):
        corner = (30 + 3 * j, 70 + 3 * i)
        if i and j:
            corners.append(corner)
        if (i % 2) ^ (j % 2):
            img[corner[0]:corner[0] + 3, corner[1]:corner[1] + 3] = 255
corners = np.array(corners)

>>> cv2.estimateChessboardSharpness(img, (9, 7), corners)
calcEdgeSharpness: checkerboard too small for calculation.
((9999.0, 9999.0, 9999.0, 9999.0), None)

The line appears to be a simple std::cout << ..., so I have tried all of the following:
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from os imoprt devnull
import sys

with redirect_stdout(None):
    cv2.estimateChessboardSharpness(img, (9, 7), corners)

with open(devnull, "w") as null, redirect_stdout(null):
    cv2.estimateChessboardSharpness(img, (9, 7), corners)

sys.stdout = open(devnull, "w")
cv2.estimateChessboardSharpness(img, (9, 7), corners)

I've even tried redirect_stderr instead of redirect_stdout just in case. I've also tried setting OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL=SILENT in bash and os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"] = "SILENT" in python before importing cv2, not that I expected stdout to be conflated with logging in this case.
In all cases, the message prints. How do I make it stop?

You're redirecting the python sys.stdout file object, not the underlying C FILE *stdout or the file descriptor below that. Non-Python code isn't going to be using the Python file object. os.dup2 will work, but it's ugly.

@Useless. Ugly is fine. How do you do it?

Assuming a UNIX-like platform, (you'll get an OSError if not)
You can save the underlying fd with
backup = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())

point it to a different file (eg. different) with
os.dup2(different.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())

and resume normal service with
os.dup2(backup, sys.stdout.fileno())

Do note that this won't behave at all nicely if the file you redirect to is also being used for buffered output (ie, you have writes to different mixed with C++ library writes to std::cout which is using different.fileno()...)

Will select if it works. This is not ugly at all. In fact, it's basically one context manager away from being quite easy

The fact that it's platform-specific, and drilling down two layers of abstraction, is the ugly part. At least it isn't also hard.

Fair enough. Also, FWIW, this should work on Windows according to the docs. I haven't seen a Windows machine for a long time now, so I don't really care :)

Should I be closing backup after finishing? My gut says yes, but I'm still not 100% on what fileno really is.

It's just another reference to stdout in practice. You don't really need to close it unless you're running out of file descriptors, but tidyness is a good enough reason.

Perfect: https://gitlab.com/madphysicist/haggis/-/blob/master/src/haggis/os.py?ref_type=heads#L315

Very nice implementation!
